# I was asking a question but I accidently did it under Answers, how can I rectify?

Tags: discussion

Earlier today I found your website but asked a question before I knew how it worked.  See my title

Comment: Your account is registered, so you should be able to see the deleted answer to copy-paste from if you can't remember what all you wrote.

Answer (score 5):

First, don't worry. We know that people are not accustomed to our "one question - many answers" format and come with the expectation that we work like a forum.

You are welcome to ask about anything which is [on-topic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For this, you can simply use the rightmost button in the navigation ribbon, Ask Question. [image]

When you do this, you will get a box where you can type your own question. It gets a "thread" all to itself, and all the answers will be about it (we mods will take care to keep them to the point). Thus information can be found much easier later, as it is bundled around a single question. Also, you can later accept the answer which helped you most.

Your old post was deleted, to keep others' people questions focused on one thing. This is unfortunate for you, as you have to write it up again (sadly, the system does not have the function to turn it into a question for you, keeping the text) but it has no other bad consequences. You don't lose reputation (the points you see under people's names), you are not earmarked as "bad citizen", nothing. Everybody forgets and moves on.

We have quite a few rules, which new people tend to find tedious. But they ensure that we collect information which others find useful. I know it is a bit hard to orient yourself as a new user. But you have several options, all conveniently bundled in the Help menu: 
[image]

- First, there is a very short [tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) giving you a rough impression of the basics.
- The second point, [Help center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help), contains a very extensive list of pages explaining different topics in detail
- If you are still unsure about something, you can ask us a question about how the site works. This is done not on the main site, but on its so-called Meta site, on which we are now. It is accessed through the third link in the Help menu. It works similar to the real Seasoned advice site, but instead of question about cooking, it is for questions about how Seasoned advice works.

When you are on Meta, the first link in the Help center takes you back to the main [Seasoned advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see it listed on your profile, so I presume a moderator deleted it. All you have to do to rectify is go ahead and ask it as a question (but please read the help that shows up on the right on the "Ask a Question" page.)

At very minimum, please [take the tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour). It's short!